# Uniform closure vs. dense

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis

Let $S_1= \{z\in \mathbb{C} \}$ be the unit circle in the complex plane. Let $A$ be the set of all polynomial functions on $\mathbb{C}$ restricted to $S^1$. That is $A= \{ f: S^1 \rightarrow \mathbb{C}; f(e^{i\theta})= \sum_{k=0}^n c_ke^{ik\theta}, c_k\in \mathbb{C}\}$. Either prove that the uniform closure of $A$ is all of $C(S^1)$, or give an example with justification to show that it is not.

By the complex version of Stone-Weierestrass, we know $A$ is dense in $C(S^1)$. Does this prove that the uniform closure of $A$ is all of $C(S^1)$? In general, do "being dense in" and the "being uniform closure of" mean the same thing?

Thanks!

Comment: Dense in $C(S^{1})$ w.r.t. the usual sup norm is same as having uniform closure equal to $C(S^{1})$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is. Since uniform limit of a sequence of continuous function is a continuous function.

Answer (score 1):

So, do you think the "conjugation"  function $g(e^{i\theta}) = e^{-i\theta}$, which is continuous on $S_1$, is a uniform limit of polynomials as in $A$?

For $f \in A$,
$$
\int_0^{2\pi} e^{i\theta} f(e^{i\theta})\,d\theta =
\int_0^{2\pi}\sum_{k=0}^n c_ke^{i(k+1)\theta}d\theta = 0
\tag1$$
but
$$
\int_0^{2\pi} e^{i\theta} g(e^{i\theta})\,d\theta =
\int_0^{2\pi}1\; d\theta = 2\pi.
\tag2$$
Thus a uniform limit of functions $f$ as in $(1)$ cannot be the function $g$ as in $(2)$.

Comment: Perhaps look up the "complex version of Stone-Weierstrass".

Comment: +1 but I"d replace "Perhaps" with "Definitely".